# Ionic3 Item list not updating when I change array *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have a list of item (chat message) to display with Firebase Realtime Database. 
That my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
...
 var self = this;
 self.ref.limitToLast(20).on('value',data => {
   console.log('chat message added');
   self.chatMessages = [];
   data.forEach( data => {
            self.chatMessages.push({
                key: data.key,
                message: data.val().message
            });
   });
 });
 ...
}
```

That's my HTML code:

```
<ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let chatMessage of chatMessages">
        <p>{{chatMessage.message}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In browser It works fine, but when I tried to test on Android real device I have side effect: I can view the message "chat message added" in console debug (chatMessages array is full) but the DOM is not synchronized.
If I want to show then new list (a new message sent from other user) I have to click on screen. It seems strange, but just click anywhere in the application screen and the list is displayed.

Anyone can help me ? I'm using Ionic 3.

Comment: Try to use [angular 2 change detection](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

Comment: To solve I use NgZone: this.ngZone.run(() => {...self.chatMessages.push...}